# Правильно ли привожу наследуемый объект к другому типу класса, который тоже наследуется?

Tags: c++, ооп

Верно ли я делаю или стоит что-то изменить? Есть ли утечка памяти?

A.cpp:

```
class B;
class C;

class A { 
public: 
    A() = default;
    B* makeMeB();
    C* makeMeC();
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

A::B* makeMeB() {
    return new B();
}

A::C* makeMeC() {
    return new C();
}
```

B.cpp:

```
class B : public A {
    public:
    B() = default;
    virtual ~B() = default;
};
```

C.cpp:

```
class C : public A {
    public:
    C() = default;
    virtual ~C() = default;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
int main () {
    B* b1 = new B();
    C* c1 = b1.makeMeC();
    delete b1, c1;
}
```

Comment: 1) этот код не скомпилируется 2) приведения наследуемого объекта к другому типу класса, который тоже наследуется тут нигде не выполняется 3) `delete b1, c1;` делает не то, что вы думаете, что он делает

Comment: @VTT, а как стоит лучше выполнить это преобразование? Подскажите, в чем конкретно ошибка здесь?

Comment: Какое преобразование? `B` в `С`? Это невозможно.

Comment: @VTT да. почему невозможно? мы же имеем общего предка, даже если класс A абстрактный

Comment: Их можно привести к общему предку, да. А друг к другу, или любому другому классу, наследуемому от `A` - нет.

Comment: @VTT, да, вот это и подразумевал. пример, который я написал - некорректен для этого вопроса?

Comment: Много неправильных вещей написали, но всё исправимо. Не могу найти приведение класса к другому. Покажите какой класс к какому.

Comment: Бессмысленный вопрос + бессмысленный ответ. В заголовке вопроса сказано, что нужно выполнить приведение типа. Почему в качестве "принятого" помечен ответ, в котором нет никакого приведения типа? Где вообще формулировка задания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что класс `А` не имеет членов указателей на `С` или `В`, поэтому это:

```
A::B* makeMeB() {
    return new B();
}

A::C* makeMeC() {
    return new C();
}
```

заменить на:

```
B* A::makeMeB() {
    return new B();
}

C* A::makeMeC() {
    return new C();
}
```

Во вторых в вашей программе нет никакого преобразования, а есть ошибка использования указатель типа вместо обьекта типа:

```
 C* c1 = b1.makeMeC(); // нет
```

А нужно:

```
 C* c1 = b1->makeMeC();
```

или

```
 C* c1 = (*b1).makeMeC();
```

И поскольку  метод `makeMeC` возвращает именно `С*` , то преобразований никаких не наблюдается...
 Также, вместо

```
 delete b1, c1;
```

нужно

`delete b1; delete  c1;`

Так вы освободите память, выделенная в программе и функцией, и никаких утечек не будет

И, как замечание, не имеющее отношение к вопросу:  все три класса  не имеют  инкапсулированных данных.  Для читабельности и хорошего восприятия, лучше такие сущности определить как структуру. В таком случаи отпадает и нужда для спецификатора доступа `public`

Comment: Утечку памяти в `delete b1,c1;` добавьте...

Comment: AlexGlebe 17, да, выправы